# React form input won't let me change value

Tags: reactjs, laravel, forms

I have a component in a React class in my Laravel project which is a simple form with one input field. It houses a phone number which I have retrieved from the database and passed back through the reducer and into the component as a prop. Using this, I have passed it through to the module as a prop which then populates the field with the currently saved value:

```
<OutOfOfficeContactNumberForm
    show={props.showOutOfOffice}
    value={props.outOfOfficeNumber}
    handleChange={console.log("changed")}
/>
```

I have a `handleChange` on here which is supposed to fire a console log, but it only ever displays on page load. Here is my form module class:

```
class OutOfOfficeContactNumberForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { show, value, handleChange } = this.props;

        if(!show) return null;

        return (
            <div>
                <p>
                    Please supply an Out of Office contact number to continue.
                </p>
                <InputGroup layout="inline">
                    <Label layout="inline" required={true}>Out of Office Contact Number</Label>
                    <Input onChange={handleChange} value={value} layout="inline" id="out-of-office-number" name="out_of_office_contact_number" />
                </InputGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default (CSSModules(OutOfOfficeContactNumberForm, style));
```

The form is embedded in my parent component, as follows:

```
return (
    <SectionCategoriesSettingsForm
        isSubmitting={this.state.isSubmitting}
        page={this.props.page}
        show={this.props.show}
        categories={this.props.categories}
        submitSectionCategoriesSettings={this._submit.bind(this, 'add')}
        updateSelectedCategories={this._updateSelectedCategories.bind(this)}
        selectedCategoryIds={this.state.selectedCategoryIds}
        storedUserCategories={this.props.selectedCategories}
        outOfOfficeNumber={this.state.outOfOfficeNumber}
        onUpdateContactNumber={this._updateContactNumber.bind(this)}
    />
);
```

In my `componentWillReceiveProps()` function, I set the state as follows:

```
if (nextProps.selectedCategories && nextProps.selectedCategories.length > 0) {
    this.setState({
        outOfOfficeNumber: nextProps.outOfOfficeNumber,
        selectedCategoryIds: nextProps.selectedCategories.map(c => c.id)
    });
}
```

I'm pretty sure the reason it's not changing is because it's pre-loaded from the state which doesn't change - but if I cannot edit the field how can I get it to register a change?

**EDIT**: Just to clarify there are also checkboxes in this form for the user to change their preferences, and the data retrieved for them is set the same way but I am able to check and uncheck those no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Changes:**

**1-** `onChange` expect a function and you are assigning a value that's why, put the console statement inside a function and pass that function to`OutOfOfficeContactNumberForm` component , like this:

```
handleChange={() => console.log("changed")}
```

**2-** You are using controlled component (using the value property), so you need to update the value inside onChange function otherwise it will not allow you to change means input values will not be not reflect in ui.

Check example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    input1: '',
    input2: '',
  }
  
  onChange = (e) => this.setState({ input2: e.target.value })
  
  render() { 
    return(
      <div>
        Without updating value inside onChange 
        <input value={this.state.input1} onChange={console.log('value')} />
        <br />
        Updating value in onChange 
        <input value={this.state.input2} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: There is already an onChange attribute on the Input - but although I understand your example, I would need to pass through the value prop to get the actual value of the field, which means this example won't really work...

Comment: used that example to demonstrate that, even if you assign a onChange property to input element and not changing the value inside that, then also field will be not editable. so idea is if you are using value property then use onChange and update the value inside that :)

Comment: check the updated answer, assigned a value to onChange, let me know if i missed something in explanation :)

Comment: I see - thank you. I'm currently trying to assign the value prop to a new state in the component (as you have done with the state 'input2') but due to the nature of states, it's not setting it in time before the render so I need to keep working on it...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is when you get data from database put it to state and pass the state to input and remember if you want to see input changes in typing, use a function to handle the change and that function should change state value.

Answer (score 0):

```
class payloadcontainer extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props)     
         this.state = {
              number:1
         }
     }    

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <input value={this.state.number} onChange={(e)=>this.setState({number:e.target.value})}></input>
                <button onClick={()=>this.props.buyCake(this.state.number)}><h3>buy {this.state.number} cake </h3></button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be able add some explanation ?